# RequireJS: What is the name-value pair example (1.2.1 in the docs) used for?

Tags: requirejs

From RequireJS's documentation (1.2.1), it has an example of simple name-value pair with no dependencies.

```
//Inside file my/shirt.js:
define({
    color: "black",
    size: "unisize"
});
```

It doesn't have a return statement, so it doesn't look like any other module could get the values.

How would I use this or access the values in here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to include that module inside of another you would expose it's contents:

my/shirt.js:

```
define({
    color: "black",
    size: "unisize"
});
```

shirtstore.js:

```
define(["my/shirt"], function(shirt) {
    console.log(shirt.color);
    console.log(shirt.size);
}
```

Basically the contents of shirt.js become an object that you get access to when declaring that as a dependency of another module.